# Ways to optimize application using yaml config files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, yaml

I created a web-survey application using rails. The administrator specify each survey sections, questions, validations and possible answers/types of answers in yaml config files.

For now, I load the yaml config files for sections and questions at each request (on each page). I know I can use cache to optimize database queries, but would it be faster to use cache also for reading yaml config files? And what kind of cache would you suggest? memcache, binary file, other?

Thanks for any help on this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Knuth said it best with...

"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Unless its a problem, move on with your life. However to avoid being ranked down for snarkyness...

In this case, you could read your config files into Class constants to avoid File I/O when you need to retrieve the information if you really think it's going to be a problem.

However based upon your problem what you're probably trying to do could be done better with [Backbone Forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) but then you'd be adding complexity with JavaScript.

Comment: Well, thanks! I think I can try to put the data in class constants, since I think I read somewhere they are cached in production environment by default.

Comment: also check out this article if you need them to be immutable [Constant Freezing](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/153861)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using yaml files actually, unless there is a very good reason for it. You should use your DB instead. It would be much more user friendly and easier to maintain if you used nested models with the correct associations. This [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) actually is almost identical to your situation.

Comment: That is what I want to create later on, but for now, I can't do that because of limited time to develop the administrator forms (backend)